Reuse a section of Facelets code within the same Facelets file
Is there a way to declare a block or section of Facelets code to be reused within the same Facelet?
Sort of like:
<html>

    <ui:repeatablesection>
      Make your choice
    </ui:repeatablesection>

    ...

    <ui:repeatablesection /> of cars

    <ui:repeatablesection /> of houses

</html>

I know this can be done with ui:include and templating, but I'd rather not have to create separate files.
Using JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 10.

Nope, but that's a great suggestion for next Faces version. Request it here: https://github.com/jakartaee/faces/issues
